# Giving MYSQL error again and again

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have hosted a new head tail gaming site. But I continously get this error message on my Index and History page.

Index Page:Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1906451/public_html/index.php on line 233

History Page:Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1906451/public_html/history.php on line 106

Any solution friends? Please help me out.

Comment: Please post the code around the mysql_num_rows() functions in the 2 files

Comment: This question really shouldn't be tagged with "android" or "iphone".

Comment: Are you able to access any items from your query result? Sounds like there is a problem with the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

change `mysql_num_rows` to `@mysql_num_rows` in index.php on line 233 and in history.php ind line 106

Comment: This will just suppress warnings in both cases, and may just end up masking a wider problem. I'd suggest to the OP that the problem should be traced to a point earlier in the code.

Comment: Frederick Behrends thanks for your suggestion. Changing mysql_num_rows to @mysql_num_rows WORKED!!!!!!! Now my site is up Perfectly. Thank You once again. You can also see the change. Go to alertflips.co.cc and alertflips.co.cc/history.php. Thanks once again!!!! YAHOOOOOO!!!!

Comment: @Morning Star - that doesn't mean your code is actually *working*, it just means that PHP is silently ignoring the error.  You should really consider actually *fixing* the problem rather than just preventing it from appearing.

Comment: Probably one of the worst answers i have seen in SO.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to mysql_num_rows() expects a valid MySQL result.  Most likely, you're ignoring an error from mysql_query() or trying to look at a query that doesn't return a usable result object.